# Gentoo virtualbox X support

Tags: linux, virtualbox, virtual-machine, kernel, gentoo

So i wanted to play around in gentoo to level up my linux knowledge.

I've installed it on virtualbox, but i didn't add a few USE flags, and during core compilation i didn't select a few necessary features to run X server on virtualbox. 
Described in here: https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/VirtualBox

Is my only solution now to re-install gentoo, or is there a way to recompile the kernel with the right USE flags etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always recompile the kernel. You should follow a guide tailored for your distro.

This link to gentoo wiki should suffice: http://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Kernel/Upgrade